# How to pass the random item to the dropdown list of a view.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MCV app with Razor syntax.
I have pass the elements to the dropdown list and I want to pass the any random item to the view, as oer than item , dropdown list item will be selected. 
below code displays the dropdow code.

> Controller Code

```
  [SessionFilterAction]
            public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {

 ViewBag.HODList = new SelectList(db.Employees.Where(e => e.DesignationType == "HOD"), "Id", "FullName");
            ViewBag.ItemToBeSelectedInList = 5;
            return View(paymentadvice);
    }
```

> View Code

```
 if(ViewBag.DesignationTypeOfLoggedUser == "Staff")
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("HODList", String.Empty ,new { ???? })
    }
```

Now I want to use viewbag element which will be select the one of the item of dropdown.
How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`constructor of the SelectList class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which allows you to specify the id of the item to be selected:

```
[SessionFilterAction]
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    int itemToBeSelectedInList = 5;
    ViewBag.HODList = new SelectList(
        db.Employees.Where(e => e.DesignationType == "HOD"), 
        "Id", 
        "FullName",
        itemToBeSelectedInList
    );
    return View(paymentadvice);
}
```

This being said, using ViewBag is bad practice and I would recommend you switching to using view models and strongly typed helpers in the view.

Comment: tried the same code but Not working....it shows the first item selected in the dropdown by default

Answer (score 1):

@Html.DropDownList selects item with flag Selected (SelectListItem.Selected = true).
SelectList has constructor which automatically set this flag for specified item:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue)
```

selectedValue should be the id of the employee that will be selected :

```
var employees = db.Employees.Where(e => e.DesignationType == "HOD").ToList();
var selectedEmployeeId = employess[5].Id;
ViewBag.HODList = new SelectList(employees, "Id", "FullName", selectedEmployeeId );
```

Comment: tried the same code but Not working...it shows the first item selected in the dropdown by default

Comment: try to specify select list into DropDownList helper method : @Html.DropDownList("HODList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.HODList )